Django channels async websocket group_send not working
I've created an async web socket with the below code:
class AgentSessionAsyncConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.session = None
        self.group_name = None

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_session(self, session_id):
        return Session.objects.active().get(pk=session_id)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def close_session(self):
        self.session.close()

    async def connect(self):
        session_id = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["session_id"]
        try:
            self.session = await self.get_session(session_id)
            self.group_name = str(self.session.chat_id)
            await self.accept()
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                self.group_name,
                self.channel_name,
            )
        except Session.DoesNotExist:
            await self.close()

    async def disconnect(self, code):
        if self.session is not None:
            await self.close_session()
            await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
                self.group_name,
                self.channel_name,
            )

    async def send_to_client(self, data, typ="message"):
        payload = {
            "type": typ,
            "data": data,
        }
        await self.send_json(payload)

        
    # receivers for chat.message & chat.ack (called from above consumer)
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        await self.send_to_client(event["content"])

    async def chat_ack(self, event):
        await self.send_to_client(event["content"], typ="ack")


To send msg to the above web socket, I call the below broadcast function as utils.broadcast(msg) in sync view of Django views.

def broadcast(msg, typ=BroadcastType.Message):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    group_name = str(msg["chat_id"])
    if typ == BroadcastType.Message and msg["from_user"]:
        enabled, token = can_send_custom_message([msg])
        msg["_extra"] = {"enable_reply": enabled, "reply_token": token}

    payload = {
        "type": typ,
        "content": msg,
    }
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(group_name, payload)

Now, whenever I hit the API, it gets stuck at async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(group_name, payload) line of broadcast. I tested this by putting logs before and after the same line.
But whenever, I try to run the same code in the docker container shell, it executes correctly.
Container shell output - The indicates - channels are correctly configured in the docker environment.
Also, Websocket gets created successfully on the front end but it does not receive msgs whenever API is hit but receives msgs when executed explicitly through the shell.
What can I do to troubleshoot?
